# OpenLayers3 get feature request for more than one point in the same place

Tags: javascript, openlayers, overlay, getfeatureinfo

I created a map that brings up a popup overlay on click, the [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/86qvt32b/8/). The only issue I have now is if I have two points in the same location it.

As you can see with the Birmingham point, when you click on the point it only brings up the value of the point written in last (on top), ideally I would like it to show the values of any points that are in this location?

Comment: Again I suggest you [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuDYJe?p=preview).

Comment: For a follow-up, see opened issue on official repo by Jonatas https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, you have to create an offset between the markers to the user be able to click on each.

My suggestion is to listen `pointermove` event and show the markers separately. I was facing with this same issue and [here is my solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuDYJe?p=preview).

**UPDATE**

So, based on comments. My idea is: create an array attribute of the features id at the same location. On click check this attr and then proceed the way you want.

```
var birmingham = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.900878, 52.483952])),
    name: 'Birmingham',
    address: 'Here Address',
    Number:'7',
    children: [2,3]
});
```

[Your fiddle forked](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ukrt51e7/1/).

Comment: Thanks @Jonatas, this works as a nice work-around, however the solution I need has to bring through all of the attributes in one list. 

I have achieved this using a getElementByID command that then brings this into a table, but have not managed to convert this into an overlay yet.

Comment: You question was: You have two points (markers) at the same location. How to show them individually? Am I right? So, step by step.

Comment: yes sorry, i should have been more clear. When i click on that one specific location, no matter how many points are in that same place, I want it to list the details of that point in the one overlay. Not sure if this is any clearer? Thanks again.

Comment: So, you want a **single** marker with all the details in it?

Comment: Yes, one popup, that in the case of the JSFiddle example that I put at the start will list "Birmingham" and "Birmingham2" in the same popup as they are in the same place.

Comment: Thanks @Jonatas, you're updated solution works well for my question so I've marked it as correct. However, for the solution i'm looking for this won't quite work as i'm bringing through data from a remote server that I can't add attributes on to.

Comment: But you don't add attrs on remote data. When data is loaded you change features, add attributes and so on.