# Show clustered features beside each other in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, clustering

I have a map with clustered features, like in the picture. As you can see in the image some points have the same coordinates. What I want to do is when I'm at a certain zoom level and the points have identical coordinates I want to split them up so that the are beside each other so that the user can click on one of them.

Is this something that is possible to do with OpenLayers and clustered features?

```
const clusterSource = new olCluster({
            distance: 36,
            source: heatmapSource
});

const styleCache = {};
        this.clusterLayer = new olVectorLayer({
            visible: false,
            source: clusterSource,
            style: (feature) => {
                const size = feature.get('features').length;
                let style = styleCache[size];
                if (!style) {
                    style = new olStyle({
                        image: new olCircle({
                            radius: 8,
                            stroke: new olStroke({
                                color: '#000'
                            }),
                            fill: new olFill({
                                color: [153, 0, 0, Math.min(0.9 + (size / Math.max(positions.length)))]// '#3399CC'
                            })
                        }),
                        text: new olText({
                            text: size.toString(),
                            fill: new olFill({
                                color: '#fff'
                            })
                        })
                    });
                    styleCache[size] = style;
                }
                return style;
            }
        });
```

[image: Map with clustered features]

Comment: Try this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149581/openlayers3-get-feature-request-for-more-than-one-point-in-the-same-place

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CuDYJe?p=preview&preview